# Traverse AccessibilityNodeInfos in AccessibilityService

Tags: android, accessibilityservice, accessibility

I currently retrieve the root node of the active window with `getRootInActiveWindow()`. Afterwards, I perform a breadth first search to get a list of all nodes.

My questions:
How can I traverse this list of nodes to get the focus order? Is this list ordered according to the nodes' focus order already? Is there a different approach of retrieving the focus order?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean focus order, or do you mean accessibility_focus order?

Comment: I'm talking about input focus. See 'Focus Order': https://material.io/guidelines/usability/accessibility.html#accessibility-hierarchy-focus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ultimately, no. You cannot, and the accessibility api documentation on this is very misleading.

One might think that the "focusSearch(int direction)" function of AccessibilityNodeInfo would be the way to go. But, ultimately it is broken, and if you go back into the inards of the Android Accessibility APIs you end up finding a function that's documented as such:

> Searches for the nearest view in the specified direction that can take the input focus.

COOL, just what we want right?  HOLD ON A SECOND. This function calls a function

```
AccessibilityInteractionClient.getInstance().focusSearch(mConnectionId, mWindowId, mSourceNodeId, direction);
```

And this function is documented as such:

> Finds the accessibility focused {@link android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo}. The search is performed in the window whose id is specified and starts from the node whose accessibility id is specified.

Dissappointingly, you will also find that this function does neither of those jobs (directional focus search, or directional accessibility focus search) well.

Ultimately, when an element in TalkBack gains accessibility focus due to the focus of an element, it's actually responding to the actual focus event coming from the OS and NOT any calculation that TalkBack is doing on input focus ordering.

In order to do this, you would basically have to implement the entire logic from the OS for Tab Ordering yourself, with less information the system itself has to do it, because the System has real `android.widget.View` objects to deal with, not fake `AccessibilityNodeInfo` objects with limited information. Any way you can come up to do this is going to be exceptionally fragile, and not guaranteed to line up with what the system actually does.

Your inclination to try a breadth first traversal of "input focusable" (the `focusable` property of `AccessibilityNodeInfo`) is a pretty reasonable solution. The problem is going to be, that the real system Tab Ordering is going to be a subset of that, which ignores things like elements existing on different windows and such.

Seriously, open up the TalkBack settings screen, turn on TalkBack, connect a hardware keyboard, go crazy on the tab and shift tab keys, and marvel at how you can't put focus on the "Settings" button. Your traversal function would get this wrong, because the "Settings" button is `focusable` but somehow, you can't put focus there. The reason why digs into some serious AOSP nonsense that I will omit, and no, I'm not sure if the information that would keep this corner case from coming up in your theoretical algorithm is available to AccessibilityServices.

To summarize, the breadth first traversal can theoretically work, but there are going to be a ton of corner cases, and no I'm not sure if the information to deal with each corner case correctly is available to AccessibilityServices. Also, notably, because of this particular issue, if you'd like the solution to be correct across 4.4, 5.0 and 7.0+ devices, you will have to have different variations of this calculation for different OS versions. YEP, those corner cases are going to be different! (Queue Evil Laughter).

My honest recommendation... give up.